# JS/JQuery: Text changes for a few seconds and then back to original

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a < div > where I keep my score but I want when its right that my text changes to +1 so I can see I was right and then immediately changes back to my score. 
With my code he shows immediately the POINTS, that fades out and fades in again so the +1 never shows up. Can someone help pls?

```
if (x >= y){ 
score++;
$("#counter").html("+1");
$("#counter").fadeOut(3000);
$("#counter").fadeIn(3000);
$("#counter").html("POINTS" + score);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.fadeOut` in [`complete-callback`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/#fadeIn-duration-complete) of the `fadeIn` which is being invoked once the `.fadeIn` is complete.

```
if (x >= y) {
  score++;
  $("#counter").html("+1");
  $("#counter").fadeOut(3000, function() {
    $("#counter").fadeIn(3000);
    $("#counter").html("POINTS" + score);
  });
}
```

Comment: @SenneMachtelinckx, Happy to help! Kindly [accept and up-vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) the best solution which has solved 

the purpose :) __Happy coding!__

Answer (score 0):

try setTimeout

setTimeout(function(){ $("#counter").html("POINTS" + score);},2000);